# Blog prog allowing posts and comments to be accessed by owner using FTP, viewable ofline?

Tags: web-development

Is there a blog program that allows

- the whole blog to be downloaded (from my website by me) using FTP, with each post, comment and image being in a separate file (comments to a given post being saved all in the same file would also be OK)
- the blog to be viewed offline having saved those files e.g. on a flash drive
- posts (and sometimes comments) to be written offline (all the better if I can do this using HTML), and then uploaded using FTP?

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [python](http://python.org) library [Nikola](https://getnikola.com) to generate a static blog web site with the source code also uploaded to the site for FTP download if need or can be stored on github or a similar service in which case all the information to regenerate your site can be downloaded with git or mercurial.  All of your posts are actually stored as ReStuctured Text.

You add posts from the command line, regenerate and publish your site

Comments facility can be provided as one of:

- DISQUS
- IntenseDebate
- LiveFyre
- Moot
- Google+
- Facebook
- isso

With the first of these *at least* allowing you to export all the comments for download.

- Free *(Gratis & Open Source)* and portable - works on OS-X, Windows 7-10, Linux, Raspberry Pie, etc.
- Download your site source, (if you don't have it already), by a various mechanisms - the source is very small so downloads are fast.
- All your authoring is done offline, from the command line *or in just about any editor* and published when **you ** choose.
- Content can be written in any of:

  - reStructuredText
  - Markdown
  - iPython Notebooks
  - HTML
  - PHP
  - any of Textile, DocBook, LaTeX, MediaWiki, TWiki, OPML, Emacs Org-Mode, txt2tags, Microsoft Word .docx, EPUB, Haddock markup
- Does not require any server side scripting, or software, so just about any hosting service is suitable.
- Fast uploads - only the changes are uploaded when you publish a new/updated blog entry.

Comment: Thanks for this. This looks as though it will do the job. Getnikola.com seems to be down though, the current site for Nikola being at Github here: https://github.com/getnikola